# A scheduled batch with java program

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I have written a java code which pulls Active Directory user details.
However I need to schedule this program to run daily with a batch script possibly.

I do not know how to perform this.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: There's the system Task Scheduler in Windows for you to schedule any job you like, but what specifically do you mean by *‘with a batch script possibly’*? Do you already have the batch script that you want to schedule or do you want to know both how to schedule and how to run your Java code with a batch script?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the `crontab` command: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron. It's not the easiest syntax to work with but it will run a command with a defined frequency...

Comment: If it's a batch file and Active Directory, it's probably not Unix, which means there probably isn't cron available, unless it's some third-party program.

Comment: Correct this is Windows.